# How to install Ubuntu 22.04 LTS on old Acer Aspire 5720 ICL50

Tags: boot, grub2, live-usb, bootloader, acer

This old Acer 5720 ICL50 already runs Ubuntu 20.04 Bionic Beaver  and Linux Mint 20.3Una on 2 separate partitions.  Both work fine and I update monthly.  The machine is only used a reference machine, not for everyday use.

I decided to install Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Jammy Jellyfish on it.  I downloaded the ISO using a Lenovo T410 I use everyday and burnt it to 16GB USB stick.  I booted successfully from the stick on the Lenovo and "tried" the new version - all fine.

Inserting stick in Acer and trying to boot achieves very little.  It boots, and displays "GRUB" top left of screen, a few moments later the grub menu but thereafter just a flashing underscore top left of screen and nothing thereafter.

Is my old Acer just too old?  Or is there something I could press during boot?  Maybe, get into the stick and change something?  Is there anything else I need to supply to try and answer these questions?

I tried using GNOME disks to write the ISO to the stick with the same problem. In the end I reluctantly booted another Lenovo T410 running Windows,downloaded the ISO and used Rufus to burn onto the stick. And this worked! A quick GRUB followed by WELCOME and the usual menu where I could run up the live USB, and try the Jellyfish. I will think about installing another day.

So,to conclude I have managed to partly answer my own question - no idea whether I will actually manage to install fully. I am guessing Rufus managed to do MBR with EFI/BIOS whereas Startup Disc and GNOME discs wasn't.

Do I raise a bug?

Comment: What boot options are selected in Acer's BIOS?

Comment: There are no boot options in the Acer BIOS other than the boot sequence order.

Comment: I noticed during the boot from USB something about "cannot find grub_platform".  I googled and found some answers in askubuntu which I inferred was because I created the USB in a different environment (Lenovo T410) than the one I intended trying it in - the Acer.  So, I booted the Acer into 20.04 from the hard drive, downloaded the 22.04 ISO, burnt it to a new USB using Startup Disk creator once more, re-booted into this new USB stick and exactly the same problem.  It shouldn't be like this.  I shouldn't need to get into the inner workings of grub and/or BIOS/UEFI - time to report a bug?